# Div is overlapping one another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: overlapping]

I'm trying to add another section under the jumbotron but it overlaps jumbotron for some reason..

Here is my code

http://www.bootply.com/IUd0GWEuAn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section overlaps because you have applied `position: absolute` on jumbotron. Elements with `absolute` or `fixed` are taken out from the normal flow of `DOM` so they overlap with other elements. You can set your `navbar` with `position: absolute` rather than jumbotron and it will work.

**Sample Code**

```
<nav class="navbar">
     // navigation
</navbar>
<div class="jumbotron">
    // jumbotron
</div>
<div class="next-section">
    // next section
</div>

body {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.next-section {
  // styling will go here...
}
```

I've updated your code, have a look at it. You can play with css to make it exactly according to your needs. [Link](http://www.bootply.com/zBeavLU9sk)

Comment: @Uzer you are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `<div style="clear:both"></div>` right after the upper bar.

Answer (score 0):

The jumbotron is the class of boostrap having impact on the text you should also have to assign the columns to occupy for defining its width.assign col-lg-12 or row with jumbotron class to the wrapper div.